# How to integrate knowlarity api in php?

Tags: php, jquery, api

I have a api where i have to send the request and get the response of call recording and other details of customers. i have developer account but right now i am not getting any details in response objects.

```
 $curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://kpi.knowlarity.com/Basic/v1/account/calllog",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "authorization: *****",
      "cache-control: no-cache",
      "channel: Basic",
      "content-type: application/json",
      "end_time: 2017-03-14 12:00:00+05:30",
      "postman-token: *****",
      "start_time: 2017-03-13 12:00:00+05:30",
      "x-api-key: *****"
    ),
  ));

  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $err = curl_error($curl);

  curl_close($curl);

  if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
  } else {
    echo '<pre>';
    echo $response;
  }
```

Resonse:
       {
       "meta" : {
       "limit" : 20,
       "next" : "",
      "offset" : 0,
       "previous" : "",
      "total_count" : 0
     },
       "objects" : [
    ]
     }

https://developer.knowlarity.com/api-reference

Comment: You've just posted your API authentication credentials to a public forum, you'll want to change/revoke them immediately.

Comment: You sure the parameter channel (you used Basic) is right? Check the API console....

Comment: And remember, lots of us can see the edit history, so Alex's edit will not hide those credentials

Comment: Yes Basic is right

Comment: @RiggsFolly  how to remove the edit history

Comment: Sorry, cannot do that. Maybe contact a Moderator @deceze can you help

Comment: Basically you need to change your cred's

Comment: your response meta object show that your call total count is 0 so make sure you have recording detail

Answer (score 0):

you can include this

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

after
$curl = curl_init();

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, just use your credentials and the from-to dates you would like to receive call logs.

```
$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://kpi.knowlarity.com/Basic/v1/account/calllog",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "channel: Basic",
        "x-api-key: ********",
        "authorization: *******",
        "content-type: application/json",
        "start_time: 2018-07-01 12:00:00+05:30",
        "end_time: 2018-07-09 12:00:00+05:30",
        "cache-control: no-cache",
      ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
      echo $response;
    }
```